# Make declared variable refer to already-existing kernel symbol

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

There are two parts to this question:

1. Defining a non-exported kernel function as being at a particular address and using the same name as the non-exported kernel function.
2. Exporting a non-exported kernel function once its address is known.

This question will use `kallsyms_lookup_name` in its examples. This is no longer exported as of Linux 5.7, so this is fitting.

### Defining the non-exported function

If a developer knows the address of a kernel function that has not been exported and wishes to use it, I've  seen it typically done these ways:

```
// For `void __stack_chk_fail(void)`
void (*scf)(void) = (int (*)() ) ADDRESS;
// Called like below.
scf();

// For `struct filename *getname(const char __user *)`
static struct filename *(*getname_p)(const char __user *);
getname_p = (struct filename *(*)(const char __user *) ADDRESS;
// I actually don't know how this one is called.

// For `void machine_power_off(void)`
static void (*machine_power_off_p)(void);
machine_power_off_p = (void*) ADDRESS;
// Called like below.
(*machine_power_off_p)();
```

Now suppose that I want to use `kallsyms_lookup_name` (which is no longer exported) and I want to call it as `kallsyms_lookup_name` instead of some alias such as `kln`/`kallsyms_lookup_name_ptr`/whatever. The declaration for the function can be included in the code using `#include <linux/kallsyms.h>`, but how can I get that included declaration to refer to the address of the non-dxported `kallsyms_lookup_name`?

Making the non-exported function available

As of Linux 5.7, there is no more `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(kallsyms_lookup_name)`. After determining the address of `kallsyms_lookup_name` and after doing the above, how can it then be exported or otherwise made available to other kernel modules as `kallsyms_lookup_name`?

Comment: Have you tried to just define **your own variable** `kallsyms_lookup_name` with appropriate *pointer-to-function* type and value, and export the variable (with `EXPORT_SYMBOL`)? Or define **your own function** `kallsyms_lookup_name` which  calls a function by your **private variable** (say `kallsyms_lookup_name_ptr`), which in turn contains pointer to "real" `kallsyms_lookup_name`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I want to reuse as much code from the Linux kernel as I can. That means using the declaration of `kallsyms_lookup_symbol` from the headers and abstaining from the use of proxy variables.

Comment: "That means using the declaration of kallsyms_lookup_symbol from the headers" - Nothing prevents you to use **declaration** from the header. What you cannot to use is **definition** of the function, because of absence `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL` (or `EXPORT_SYMBOL`) for it. Only hackish ways remain.